# Sync Orchestrator define custom operations

Tags: .net, sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

i'm starting a research about .Net Sync Framework and now i'm triyng to define custom operations to handle conflits.

I'm using a Sync Orchestrator to control the sync session and at the moment i catch all the conflicts, so How to define a custom operation to execute on a conflit detection ?
the following aproach is correct ?

```
 if (e.Conflict.Type == DbConflictType.LocalInsertRemoteInsert) 
 { 
       //Set a connection to DB
       //Call a Stored Proc.
 }
```

and in this case, i dont use the standard conflict resolution from Sync Framework like:

```
e.Action = ApplyAction.Continue;
```

Ps: Im using Sync Framework 2.1 and C# language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you mean by "custom operation", if you're catching conflicts, you'll get notified when one happens. it's up to you what you want to do: resolve using the pre-defined conflict resolution in Sync Fx or fire up your own database operations/custom logic.

Comment: By "custom operation" i mean to fire my own operation like stored procedures, etc.
But how can i define that operations throw code and fire it ?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: there's nothing in the API for you to specify call this SP or run this command. You get the conflict, you write your own code to do what you want. if you want to call an SP, write code to connect to DB, run your command, whatever you want...

Comment: I edit my answer. Please verify it.
What you sugest for me to do is what i specify above ?